# How to create self-updating Node.js application?

Tags: node.js

I have a single application that is ran on n amount of servers in any given configuration (say some behind NAT etc.), thus direct push update is not really viable option.

I was planning to build an self-updater into the application, so that every instance could download the new version from, say S3, and update themselves.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather push (say via [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)) than make the application pull from somewhere and update itself?

Comment: The problem is that there is no direct access to all of the servers (say some are behind NAT), thus the server should be able to update itself. (updated the question)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [always](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/always) together with curl (or something similar for s3, for example the [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)) and unzip. Just download the file automatically, unzip it and always restarts it if necessary.