# Calling a sh script from node.js

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a node.js application, which connect everyday to a server.

On this server, a new version of the app can be available, if so, the installed app download it, check if the download is complete, and if so, stop itself calling a shell script, which replace the old app by the new one, and start it.

I m struggling at starting the update script.

I know I can start it with child_process_execFile function, which I do:

```
var execF = require('child_process').execFile;
var PATH = process.argv[1].substr(0, process.argv[1].lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    filename = 'newapp.js',
execF(PATH + 'up.sh', [PATH + filename], function () {console.log('done'); return ;});
```

up.sh, for now is just:

```
cat $1 > /home/pi/test
```

I get 'done' printed in the console, but test isn t created.

I know that execFile create a subprocess, is it what block the script to do that?

If I suceed to start this, I know I only have to make some cp in the script to have my app auto-updating.

EDIT:

Started as usual (calling the script from console), it work well, is there a reason for the script to don t execute when called from node.js?

Comment: Have you double checked that PATH is the full path and not relative?

Comment: PATH is '/home/pi/folder/', so a full path yes

Comment: Have you looked at modules that do this automatically? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918508/how-to-create-self-updating-node-js-application

Comment: @WiredPrairie: It s almost perfect, could you post this as answer so I can accept it? Also, how do I get rid from the '[always]' before each output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you consider using a module that can do this for you automatically rather than duplicating the effort. Or, at least use their technique as inspiration for you own requirements.

One example is: https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/always

It's simple to use:

```
Usage: always <app.js>
=> always app.js
```

Then, anytime your code changes, the app is killed, and restarted.

As you can see in the source, it uses the `Monitor` class to watch a specified file, and then uses `spawn` to kick it off (and of course `kill` to end the process when a change has happened).

Unfortunately, the `[always]` output is currently hardcoded into the code, but it would be a simple change/pull request I'm sure to make it optional/configurable. If the author doesn't accept your change, you could just modify a local copy of the code (as it's quite simple overall).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you spawn/exec the process you are executing the shell that will be processing the script and not the script itself.

Should be something like

```
execF("/usr/bin/sh", [PATH + 'up.sh', PATH + filename]);
```